# SQL Find Executive All Employees Reports To

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have found lots of examples to create a employee reporting structure hierarchy. However, I want to take this a little further and for each employee find the executive they report up through whom reports directly to the CEO. Given the following data:

```
ID          FullName                                           HRLevel    SupervisorID
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ------------
1           Pam Beesly                                         CEO        NULL
2           Angela Martin                                      SVP        1
3           Kelly Kapoor                                       SVP        1
4           Meredith Palmer                                    SVP        1
5           Phyllis Vance                                      AVP        3
6           Jan Levinson                                       AVP        4
7           Erin Hannon                                        Associate  5
8           Karen Filippelli                                   Intern     5
```

I would like a list of all employees with an HRLevel of SVP and below to show the SVP level employee they report up to. So it could be their immediate supervisor or it could be 4 levels above them. Also, if an employee reports directly to the CEO I want that employee to be listed as the DepartmentHead.

Here is what I have so far:

```
;WITH cte_employees (ID, FullName, HRLevel, SupervisorID, SupervisorName) AS
(
    SELECT ID
         , FullName
         , HRLevel
         , SupervisorID
         , CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NULL) AS [SupervisorName]
    FROM   #Employees
    WHERE  HRLevel = 'SVP'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     e.ID
             , e.FullName
             , e.HRLevel
             , e.SupervisorID
             , c.FullName AS [SupervisorName]
    FROM       #Employees    e 
    INNER JOIN cte_employees c
    ON e.SupervisorID = c.ID
)
SELECT c2.ID
     , c2.FullName
     , c2.HRLevel
     , c2.SupervisorID
     , COALESCE(c2.SupervisorName, c2.FullName) AS [DepartmentHead]
FROM   cte_employees c2;
```

Which yields the immediate supervisor, not the SVP DepartmentHead:

```
ID          FullName                                           HRLevel    SupervisorID DepartmentHead
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ------------ --------------------------------------------------
2           Angela Martin                                      SVP        1            Angela Martin
3           Kelly Kapoor                                       SVP        1            Kelly Kapoor
4           Meredith Palmer                                    SVP        1            Meredith Palmer
5           Phyllis Vance                                      AVP        3            Kelly Kapoor
6           Jan Levinson                                       AVP        4            Meredith Palmer
7           Erin Hannon                                        Associate  5            Phyllis Vance
8           Karen Filippelli                                   Intern     5            Phyllis Vance
```

The only difference in what I am getting and what I want is that Employee IDs 7 and 8 should have a SVP DepartmentHead of Kelly Kapoor.

Here is my [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=75d9bea8c76b8920519692aba68e041f) showing this in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are vert close:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Employees ', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Employees;

CREATE TABLE #Employees(ID INT,
FullName VARCHAR(50),
HRLevel VARCHAR(10),
SupervisorID INT)

INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES (1, 'Pam Beesly', 'CEO', NULL)
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES (2, 'Angela Martin', 'SVP', 1)
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES (3, 'Kelly Kapoor', 'SVP', 1)
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES (4, 'Meredith Palmer', 'SVP', 1)
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES (5, 'Phyllis Vance', 'AVP', 3)
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES (6, 'Jan Levinson', 'AVP', 4)
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES (7, 'Erin Hannon', 'Associate', 5)
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES (8, 'Karen Filippelli', 'Intern', 5)



;WITH cte_employees (ID, FullName, HRLevel, SupervisorID, SupervisorName) AS
(
    SELECT ID
         , FullName
         , HRLevel
         , SupervisorID
         , FullName AS [SupervisorName]
    FROM   #Employees
    WHERE  HRLevel = 'SVP'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     e.ID
             , e.FullName
             , e.HRLevel
             , e.SupervisorID
             , c.SupervisorName AS [SupervisorName]
    FROM       #Employees    e 
    INNER JOIN cte_employees c
    ON e.SupervisorID = c.ID
)
SELECT c2.ID
     , c2.FullName
     , c2.HRLevel
     , c2.SupervisorID
     , c2.SupervisorName AS [DepartmentHead]
FROM   cte_employees c2;
```